# How to convert list of tuples to multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose I have a list of tuples and I want to convert to multiple lists.

For example, the list of tuples is

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),]
```

Is there any built-in function in Python that convert it to:

```
[1,3,5],[2,4,6]
```

This can be a simple program. But I am just curious about the existence of such built-in function in Python.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

The built-in function `zip()` will almost do what you want:

```
>>> list(zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]))
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

This will give you a list of tuples. If you want to go further and arrive at a list of lists:

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])))
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: In Python, you need to convert the resulting iterator into a list to see the content: `list(zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]))`.

Comment: @MERose This answer was written for Python 2. Back in the day `zip()` and `map()` returned lists, not lazy iterators, as they do in Python 3. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I know I know. My comment was intended to avoid confusion in today's audience. Also, I forgot to write "Python 3".

Answer (score 55):

From the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html):

> zip() in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list:

Specific example:

```
>>> zip((1,3,5),(2,4,6))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Or, if you really want lists:

```
>>> map(list, zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]))
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 11):

```py
>>> a = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),]    
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Answer (score 8):

Despite `*zip` being more Pythonic, the following code has much better performance:

```
xs, ys = [], []
for x, y in zs:
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)
```

Also, when the original list `zs` is empty, `*zip` will raise, but this code can properly handle.

I just ran a quick experiment, and here is the result:

```
Using *zip:     1.54701614s
Using append:   0.52687597s
```

Running it multiple times, `append` is 3x - 4x faster than `zip`! The test script is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

N = 2000000
xs = list(range(1, N))
ys = list(range(N+1, N*2))
zs = list(zip(xs, ys))

t1 = time.time()

xs_, ys_ = zip(*zs)
print(len(xs_), len(ys_))

t2 = time.time()

xs_, ys_ = [], []
for x, y in zs:
    xs_.append(x)
    ys_.append(y)
print(len(xs_), len(ys_))

t3 = time.time()

print('Using *zip:\t{:.8f}s'.format(t2 - t1))
print('Using append:\t{:.8f}s'.format(t3 - t2))
```

My Python Version:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct 24 2017, 12:18:40)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Answer (score 7):

franklsf95 goes for performance in his answer and opts for `list.append()`, but they are not optimal.

Adding list comprehensions, I ended up with the following:

```
def t1(zs):
    xs, ys = zip(*zs)
    return xs, ys

def t2(zs):
    xs, ys = [], []
    for x, y in zs:
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
    return xs, ys

def t3(zs):
    xs, ys = [x for x, y in zs], [y for x, y in zs]
    return xs, ys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import timeit
    setup_string='''\
N = 2000000
xs = list(range(1, N))
ys = list(range(N+1, N*2))
zs = list(zip(xs, ys))
from __main__ import t1, t2, t3
'''
    print(f'zip:\t\t{timeit('t1(zs)', setup=setup_string, number=1000)}')
    print(f'append:\t\t{timeit('t2(zs)', setup=setup_string, number=1000)}')
    print(f'list comp:\t{timeit('t3(zs)', setup=setup_string, number=1000)}')
```

This gave the result:

```
zip:            122.11585397789766
append:         356.44876132614047
list comp:      144.637765085659
```

So if you are after performance, you should probably use `zip()` although list comprehensions are not too far behind.  The performance of `append` is actually pretty poor in comparison.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Claudiu's answer, you can use:

```
>>>a, b = map(list, zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]))
>>>a
[1,3,5]
>>>b
[2,4,6]
```

Edited according to @Peyman mohseni kiasari

Comment: No! it will give you `(1, 3, 5)` and `(2, 4, 6)` not lists. you should use `map(list, zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]))`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Claudiu's and Claudiu's answer and since map needs to be imported from itertools in python 3, you also use a list comprehension like:

```
[[*x] for x in zip(*[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])]
>>> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```