# a list of tuples into two lists

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples as follows: `[(12,1),(123,4),(33,4)]` and I want it to turn into `[12,123,33]` and `[1,4,4]` I was just wondering how I would go about this?

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
zipped = [(12, 1), (123, 4), (33, 4)]
>>> b, c = zip(*zipped)
>>> b 
(12, 123, 33)
>>> c
(1, 4, 4)
```

Or you could achieve something similar using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> b, c = [e[0] for e in zipped], [e[1] for e in zipped]
>>> b
[12, 123, 33]
>>> c
[1, 4, 4]
```

Difference being, one gives you a list of tuples (`zip`), the other a tuple of lists (the two list comprehensions).

In this case `zip` would probably be the more pythonic way and also faster.

Comment: Not only does this answer work, it's also a good example of how to think in python.

Comment: -1. The first example is a terrible idea - it only works on sequences, not arbitrary iterables, it's slower, and reinventing the wheel of a builtin, for a more limited case. `zip()` is the only answer that should be considered here. Putting the worst way of doing it first is misleading at best.

Comment: @Lattyware You're right, I switched the examples, the more pythonic one should go on top. I think the list comprehensions have their use case though and shouldn't be dismissed.

Comment: I took the -1 away, but there is literally no use case where the list comprehensions are a better solution here. If you *really* need a list of lists (which is extremely unlikely), [NPE's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537754/722121) is the best option.

Answer (score 9):

This is a perfect use case for [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [41]: l = [(12,1), (123,4), (33,4)]

In [42]: a, b = map(list, zip(*l))

In [43]: a
Out[43]: [12, 123, 33]

In [44]: b
Out[44]: [1, 4, 4]
```

If you don't mind `a` and `b` being tuples rather than lists, you can remove the `map(list, ...)` and just keep `a, b = zip(*l)`.

Comment: I would say just use `zip(*l)`, then, in the *unlikely* case that the asker *needs* lists and not tuples, use `map()` to make them. 99% of the time, you are not going to need to do that.

Comment: Could `l` be any iterable?

Answer (score 1):

This would be my go at it.

```
first_list = []
second_list = []

for tup in list_of_tuples:
    first_list.append(ls[0])
    second_list.append(ls[1])
```

Comment: According to my experiment, this solution is even faster than `zip`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47148258/1911674