# Change substrings in a larger string based on probability

Tags: python, bioinformatics, mutation, genome

For some overall context, I have a set of probabilities for each type of 3 letter substring (64 combinations in total) in my sequence to change to another given 3 letter substring. I want to be able to apply these probabilities onto every 3 letter substring in my sequence and change them if the probability indicates that it should.

Essentially, I want to randomly change 3 letter substrings within a very large string to another 3 letter substring based on known probabilities.

For example:

I have a string.

```
'GACTCGTAGCTAGCTG'
```

I have some probabilities for the substring 'GAC'

```
{'GAC>GAT': 0.05, 'GAC>GAG': 0.01 'GAC>GAA':0.03}
```

In this case, I would have a 5% chance of 'GAC' in my string to change to 'GAT', 1% chance 'GAC' changes to 'GAG' and 3% change 'GAC' changes to 'GAA' . What is the most efficient way to apply these probabilities for each 3 letter substring in my giant string.

Comment: Is the remaining 91% chance that it stays the same?

Comment: Yes in this example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the code below should do the trick. I cleaned up your dictionary to just have the replacement values.

What the code does is finds all of the places in the long string you give it where there is a `"GAC"` and then for each of those places it randomly chooses what to replace it with (that is why I included "GAC" in the dictionary - so it will replace "GAC" with "GAC" 91% of the time). Then `random_replace` returns the updated string.

*Note that the annotations of `str` and `dict` are just to help you understand what to pass in and not necessary if you don't want them.*

```py
import re
import random

test_string = 'GAC' * 100

replace_map = {'GAT': 0.05, 'GAG': 0.01, 'GAA': 0.03, 'GAC': 0.91}

def random_replace(to_replace: str, full_string: str, replace_map: dict) -> str:
    replace_indices = [i.start() for i in re.finditer(to_replace, full_string)]
    population, weights = list(zip(*replace_map.items()))
    print(population, weights)

    for i in replace_indices:
        full_string = full_string[:i] + random.choices(population, weights)[0] + full_string[i+len(to_replace):]

    return full_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(random_replace("GAC", test_string, replace_map))
```

To learn more about `random.choices`, reference [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution/41852266#41852266).

To learn more about why I use `zip` to create two lists from the keys and values of the dictionary, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081545/how-to-convert-list-of-tuples-to-multiple-lists).