# How to convert list of dict into two lists?

Tags: python

For example:

```
persons = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'mary'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'tom'}]
```

I want to get two lists from it:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
names = ['john', 'mary', 'tom']
```

What I did:

```
names = [d['name'] for d in persons]
ids = [d['id'] for d in persons]
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You don't need to pre-define `names` and `ids` though

Comment: nothing wrong with what you wrote beyond the unnecessary definitions- could iterate just once in a for loop and append to the 2 lists, but it's not a big performance difference

Comment: It is good as you did.

Comment: You could make it into a one-liner like so, but there's probably no performance difference: `ids, names = [d['id'] for d in persons], [d['name'] for d in persons]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd stick with using list comprehension or use @Woodford technique

```
ids,name = [dcts['id'] for dcts in persons],[dcts['name'] for dcts in persons]
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3] 
['john', 'mary', 'tom']
```

Comment: Double for loop isn't preferred

Answer (score 3):

What you did works fine. Another way to handle this (not necessarily better, depending on your needs) is to store your data in a more efficient dictionary and pull the names/ids out of it when you need them:

```py
>>> persons = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'mary'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'tom'}]
>>> p2 = {x['id']: x['name'] for x in persons}
>>> p2
{1: 'john', 2: 'mary', 3: 'tom'}

>>> list(p2.keys())
[1, 2, 3]

>>> list(p2.values())
['john', 'mary', 'tom']
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081545) question, is

```py
ids, names = zip(*map(lambda x: x.values(), persons))
```

that return tuples. If you need lists

```py
ids, names = map(list, zip(*map(lambda x: x.values(), persons)))
```

It is a little bit slower on my laptop using `python3.9` than the accepted answer but it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pandas in a vectorized fashion:

```
import pandas as pd
persons = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'mary'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'tom'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(persons)
id_list = df.id.tolist() #[1, 2, 3]
name_list = df.name.tolist() #['john', 'mary', 'tom']
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to iterate through the values of your list while unpacking your dictionaries:

```py
persons = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'mary'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'tom'}]


for x in persons:
    id, name = x.values()
    ids.append(id)
    names.append(name)
```

Comment: `persons` is not a dictionary

Comment: That does not mean you downvote the post. It is a simple mistake. The post is very Imformative though.